# The product is integrable of an integrable and a bounded measurable function

Tags: measure-theory

If we have a measure space (X, $\mathcal {A}$, $\mu$) and we assume $f:X \to R$ is $\mu$ - integrable and we also have $g:X \to R$ a bounded measurable function. How can I prove that $f\cdot g$ is $\mu$ - integrable? Is it enough to say beacause  f is $\mu$ - integrable it means $\int_X|f|d\mu<\infty$ and to show $\int_X|fg|d\mu<\infty$.? If yes how would I need to begin? Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: What is $E$? Being $\mu$-integrable means $\int_X |f|d\mu < \infty$. Using the fact that $g$ is bounded, can you show that $\int_X |fg|d \mu < \infty?$

Comment: oh thats my mistake, and to be honest not really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f$ is integrable (on a set $X$) means that $\int_X|f|d\mu<\infty$. And we want to show that $\int_X|fg|d\mu<\infty$. But if $|g(x)|<M$ for all $x$, then the function $|fg|$ is bounded from above by $M|f|$, so we have $$\int_X|fg|d\mu\leq\int_XM|f|d\mu=M\int_X|f|d\mu<\infty.$$

Your idea is right the result follows by just this observation.

Comment: It is enough to show that the integral fg is less or equal to integral f for fg to be integrable??

Comment: what would be M in this situation??

Comment: Yes it is enough, by definition of integrability, M is a constant in R since your function goes from X to R